# How can I map linux syslog to printf in C

Tags: c, linux, macros, syslog

I have a linux application running on my desk top, and I wanted to redirect the syslog() calls to printf() calls.

**Note:** I do *not* want to replace the calls, just redirect

So I wrote some code to do this:

```
#ifndef EMBED
#define syslog(level, stuff) printf("SYSLOG: %s\n", stuff)
#endif
```

Works great in the one file where I was using it. I moved this to a new file and got an error:

```
error: macro "syslog" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
```

I know the error is because the calls in the new file are mixed, some are using 2 arguments to syslog, some are using 3. I also know I need to somehow redirect this via variable argument lists, but how exactly do I do this? I haven't gotten it working yet...

As I understand it, syslog() and printf() should be:

```
void syslog(int priority, const char *format, ...)
int printf(const char *format, ...)
```

So I tried:

```
#define ERR 3
#ifndef EMBED         // This is not defined in my env, btw
#define syslog(pri, fmt, ...) printf(fmt, ...)
#endif
...
void main() {
...
syslog(ERR, "test");
```

but that gives the error:

```
error: expected expression before ‘...’ token
```

Suggestions on how this macro should look/be used?

Comment: A macro won't help *unless* you can guarantee that the `fmt` argument will *always* be a string literal.

Comment: Using a macro *is* replacing the calls, and is not redirecting.  If you just want to redirect, you probably want to look into LD_PRELOAD using RTLD_NEXT.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GCC has an extension in this area, but the most portable way of handling it is:

```
#define syslog(priority, ...)    printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

The priority is mandatory, but is ignored by the macro expansion.  The rest of the arguments (the mandatory format plus optional following arguments) are in the `__VA_ARGS__` used in the argument list to `printf()`.  This will be OK whether the format string is a constant (literal) or a variable.

---

If you want to tag the output as being for the surrogate of `syslog()`, I'd call a function other than `printf()` to do the job:

```
#define syslog(priority, ...) syslog_print(__VA_ARGS__)
```

or even

```
#define syslog(priority, ...) syslog_print(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

These would be declared as:

```
extern void syslog_printf(const char *fmt, ...);
```

or:

```
extern void syslog_printf(const char *file, int line, const char *func,
                          const char *fmt, ...);
```

The implementation is a straight-forward application of the macros in `<stdarg.h>` plus the `v*printf()` functions:

```
void syslog_printf(const char *file, int line, const char *func,
                   const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    printf("SYSLOG:%s:%d:%s: ", file, line, func);
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

You can add timestamps and whatever else you like; you can also rather easily arrange for the output to go to a file instead of standard output; you can also arrange for it to be turned on or off inside the function.  So, on average, I would replace `syslog()` with a surrogate that allows you to tune your codes use of the facilities.

In fact, since you've uncovered a requirement to change the behaviour of logging, I would suggest that instead of using `syslog()` directly in your code, you should use your own function (for example, the `syslog_printf()`, but possibly under a different name) in your code, and have various implementations of that function available to you.  The only downside to doing so is that calling the real `syslog()` is now harder — there isn't a `vsyslog()` AFAIK.  So, the basic call to `syslog()` would be done by formatting the string in `syslog_printf()` using `vsnprintf()` (or `vasprintf()` if that's available to you and memory exhaustion isn't a likely problem), and then calling `syslog()` with the preformatted string (`syslog(priority, "%s", buffer);`).  Of course, you'd also want the priority passed to the surrogate function for relay to `syslog()`.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks.

Comment: But this is different from what the OP wanted, which is to prefix the string with his own message... :-S

Comment: Would this be the [vsyslog()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0213/6m6ne38fl/index.html) you were mentioning?

Comment: @dtmland: That would be, presumably, the Solaris implementation of the `vsyslog()` that I mentioned.  It may or may not be available on other platforms.  The manual page on my Linux box (an Ubuntu 14.04 derivative, but I don't know whether this is part of the derivative or not) supplies `vsyslog()` too if `_BSD_SOURCE` is defined.  Mac OS X (10.10.3) has it too, without requiring `_BSD_SOURCE`.  I don't recall what the status quo was in 2012.  If HP-UX and AIX also have it (not improbable), then the portability risk is minimal -- Windows apart.

Comment: ([Gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/vsyslog.html) identifies "missing on some platforms: Minix 3.1.8, AIX 5.1, HP-UX 11, OSF/1 5.1, mingw, MSVC 9, BeOS", but that list isn't all that up to date; AIX is on at least version 7, ...).

Answer (score 1):

The `fmt` string is expected to contain its own formatting specifiers, which are filled in with the variadic arguments. First off, you could simply *ignore* the actual arguments and just print the formatting string. You need a variadic macro:

```
#define syslog(level, fmt, ...) printf("SYSLOG: %s\n", fmt)
```

Second, if you're willing to take a gigantic risk and expect the user to provide the formatting string as a literal rather than a variable, you can concatenate your own string:

```
#define syslog(level, fmt, ...) printf("SYSLOG[%d] " fmt, level, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

This will work for `syslog(1, "Hello");`, but not for `syslog(1, str);`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to depend on variadic macros (C99 feature), you could also do this:

```
#define syslog my_syslog

static inline int my_syslog(int prio, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int r;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    r = vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return r;
}
```

or similar.